# iCloud.com-style TimeZone Picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datetime, timezone

I'm looking for a very user-friendly jQuery-based TimeZone Picker and came across http://timezonepicker.com/ which is almost perfect but has quite a few fallbacks:

-At smaller sizes it begins to become a hinderance rather than a bonus
-Requires large amounts of imagemap writeup to function.

The single best TimeZone picker I have ever seen that is both highly usable and still very aesthetically pleasing is the one found on http://icloud.com

To see this one, go to iCloud.com, sign in and click on your account name in the top right, and choose "Account Options" then "Time Zone".

This TimeZone Picker is wonderful and I really want to mimic this on my own projects but can't seem to find a nice copy of this method online.

Does anyone know of a more iCloud-like timeZone picker for jQuery? Or better yet, if you can actually isolate the one on iCloud so it works locally and I can see just the code for the timepicker and learn from it that'd be great!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have a look at [this open-source time zone picker by Andrew Lin](https://github.com/dosx/timezone-picker).

You can easily zoom in to pin-point time zones for smaller countries/areas.

It is very easy to plug in, and works with either Google Maps or OpenLayers interface.  Be sure to try the live demos for both so you can see the differences.

I prefer the Google Maps implementation, but it may require a [commercial license from Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing), depending on what you are doing.  The OpenLayers version can be used commercially without any license restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this one for a project:
http://timezonepicker.com/

Through this url you have to generate an image and the corresponding image map, then integrate with the plugin.
Looking through the source of this page should be sufficient.
It will highlight geographical entities corresponding to the timezone.